# Angular JS update view from database

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Im building a social networking app using angular js. I have one doubt about binding the data. There is a timeline div, where all the recent posts gets displayed. Also, there is a status updater on top. Now, on page load, i fire an ajax($http) service to the DB and query all the posts, ill get the json data and i bind it to the div using ng-bind. suppose, the update the status now, how can i get the updated data to be displayed in my view without refreshing the page? I'm confused with this. Please help me out.

Thanks,
Pavan

### EDIT## - Some good folks had asked for code, here it is..im still facing issues and cannot bind my json data :( please help.

```
wall.controller('mainData', function($scope, $http)
{
$scope.status = {};
$scope.updatedStatus = {}; 
$scope.getStatus = function(){
  var uid = localStorage.getItem('_id');

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/profile/status/"+uid


    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.updatedStatus =data;            

    })

}
```

and the html part

```
 <div class="card" ng-controller="mainData"  ng-repeat="item in updatedStatus">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <img class="lv-img" src="img/profile-pics/2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="media-body m-t-5">
                                        <h2><a href="profile.html"       class="a-title">{{item.firstname+" "+item.lastname}}</a><small>{{item.record_time}}</small></h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                            <div class="card-body card-padding">
                                <p>{{item.message}} </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>
```

JSON array that im getting from server

```
[
{firstname: "Pavan"
id: 1
lastname: "Kumar"
message: "This is my first update"
record_time: "10/16/2015, 8:32:16 PM"},
{firstname: "LOL"
id: 2
lastname: "test"
message: "This is my second update"
record_time: "10/16/2015, 8:32:16 PM"}
]
```

As i said, nothing is getting displayed after i add new values to the server nor data is getting displayed with present data. But the server is returned me json object, no errors are getting displayed. something wrong in ng-repeat may be? .any help is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you share some piece of code?

Comment: Hi, yet to write that part. Im pretty sure that, i can get the updated info on refresh. But, my question is, is it possible to get it from the database. If i had bind it in ng-model, that would have updated instantly..but on click on post, im updating it to database. Is it possible to get it ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please help me with the flow, like how it should be done?. Im fairly new to Angular, so i have less idea.

Comment: Please, take learn through about  $scope and $http from any tutorial website. Thank you.

Comment: @BhushankumarLilapara I understood scope and http. When i click, post button, i would be using http service to update the status in DB. Now, for displaying in news feed after posting, can i use http service one more time and store the json response in scope.somearray and bind it to UI again? so that page will not be refreshed? Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to get the updated data from the DB you simply need to make the service call again which fires off the http request and then set the results equal to the model value that you are binding too. Angular's 2-way binding and watch system will update the UI without requiring an entire page reload.

Comment: Thanks @aus_lacy :) appreciate your help!

Comment: Or just update the data that already exists in your  service storage

Comment: I think you might not be able to understand how certain things in AngularJs works. Once you have written some of the code and try out yourself, then you'll get a better understanding. Else, Mostafa's answer below answers it perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is 3 places where the your data exist

1- the db

2- the javascript object

3- the html view

so if you did a binding the value in the javascript object will be the  same as the html view

so if you changed the value in the javascript object it will be changed in the view
in your question you said that

> i fire an ajax($http) service to the DB

i don't know if you use angular $http service or another one but if you use angular function there will be no problem but if you use a non angular function to get the http request you need to call this function at the end of the callback function of the request

```
$scope.$apply();
```

to ask the digest loop to work and apply your changes on the view

Comment: Thanks for the neat explanation. And thank you @aus_lacy for me helping me out too. Appreciate it.

Comment: Got it working. Had some div issues and thanks for $scope.$apply()